# I want to write a script to convert my .mobi files to epub

Tags: epub, mobipocket

Hey guys/girls,
I am in need of a script to turn my 100+ mobi files into epub.
I am currently using stanza (mac) to convert each file one by one.
I was wondering if someone could tell me how to do all of them at once. IE. A script that will do it for me. Time is not an issue. I just don't want to sit here and do it. I found a couple of sites that allow you to upload you file to them and they would give the epub format back to you. This is great except that they only allow one file at time as well. 
Sorry if this was not clear. English is not my first language. 
Thanks.

Comment: I aslo have linux, mac and windows machines at my disposable. So, OS is not an issue.

Comment: Learn some bash scripting: `for x in *.mobi; do <command to convert> $x; done`

Comment: That question is still high ranking in search engines so for sake of completeness let me suggest  `ebook-convert`  from already mentioned calibre-package as `<command to convert>` (https://askubuntu.com/a/396400)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), it allows bulk conversion between many ebook formats and I used it successfully on some PDFs I wanted to read on my kobo.

Comment: Thansk for the tip. That worked great. I got my nook and loaded everything on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using Calibre. You can BULK convert mobi files to epub files. Going from mobi to epub can usually be done with just the default conversion settings in Calibre (going from PDF to epub, on the other hand, typically requires a bunch of fiddling around with settings and regex in order to get it to look okay in epub). As you have mobi files it's likely you'll have them converted in no time.

Get Calibre from: http://calibre-ebook.com
Get help with Calibre from: the Calibre forum at http://www.mobileread.com (directly link: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=166 )
The online manual is here: http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/

I think you'll find writing your own script is not necessary.

Comment: Oh.  just now saw you posted this question a year ago! Hopefully you've done the bulk conversion by now! Perhaps the info I've provided will prove useful to someone else wanting to achieve a similar outcome.